# Shorter syntax for std::shared_ptr / std::make_shared

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I am tired of writing `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>` and `std::make_shared<MyClass>` and after considering [this](http://xkcd.com/1205/) I would like to find a shorter syntax.

For my short-lived scientific projects I often just need to produce code very quickly and prefer a tight syntax - just don't comment on it ;)

So I though about this:

```
#define PTR(X) std::shared_ptr<X>
#define NEW(X) std::make_shared<X>

PTR(MyClass) p = NEW(MyClass)(args)
```

or about this:

```
template<typename T> using ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
template<typename T, typename... Args>
ptr<T> make(Args... args) {
     return std::make_shared<T>(args...);
}

ptr<MyClass> p = make<MyClass>(args);
```

What do you think are the advantages/disadvantages of theses methods? Is there an even more elegant way?

Comment: The template function should be `template<typename T, typename... Args> ptr<T> make(Args&&... args) { return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`

Comment: That said, it's weird that someone grows tried of typing the name of a quite specialised and niche tool like `std::shared_ptr`. It's possible that it is simply being overused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using std::make_shared; // at file scope, after all #includes
auto p = make_shared<Bob>(a,b,c);
```

but personally I like the `std::`.

Using `auto` is good, because repeating the type twice on the same line is needless noise.

Answer (score 4):

you can use auto

```
auto p = std::make_shared<MyClass>(args);
```

Answer (score 4):

> What do you think are the advantages/disadvantages of theses methods?

They are awful. It is equivalent to

```
#define R return
```

which I have seen, because someone was too lazy to write `return`.

The problem is that in software development, most time is spent on thinking how to do, and on code maintenance. By using such macros, you are crippling the maintenance, making the maintainer's life more difficult then it should be.

> Is there an even more elegant way?

Use a proper IDE, set auto-complete to trigger on one character, and select whatever you need.

---

Ok, I skipped the template example.

You are introducing new symbols, and writing typedefs to make yourself write less code. The best code is the one not written.

If someone opens your source file, he has also to open the header where you defined those function and template alias. And that increases maintenance cost.

Seeing `std::shared_ptr`, one knows immediately what it is.

Also, what would you do for `std::unique_ptr`? Add `make1` and `ptr1`?

Answer (score -4):

Like already mentioned use auto and expand namespaces.

```
using namespace std;
....

auto allocatedInstance = make_shared<Type>(args);
```

Comment: Don't import entire namespaces.  `using std::make_shared;` is sometimes ok at file/function scope: `using namespace std;` is almost never worth the maintenance, as now every new symbol in `std` can conflict with global ones -- ik.  If you owned both namespaces, maybe, but we have inline namespaces for most such needs now.

Comment: Yup you are totally right, I always use prefix std::... But this guy here wanted to know how to make the code shorter *SHM*...